# Best way to group two structs into a third one on Go

Tags: json, loops, go, struct

I have the following structs:

```
type A1 struct {
   IdA1 string
   NameA1 string
   key string
}

type B1 struct {
   IdB1 string
   NameB1 string
   Size string
   key string
}

type C1 struct {
   IdA1 string
   Name string
   B1Set B1
}
```

and I need to create a []struct of type C1, that holds a B1Set of B1, B1 is huge more than 2K entries and A1 is just 10 entries, a really slow and inefficient implementation would be to loop over A1, and ask if B1-key is equal to A1-key and store in a map the result, but.. is there any better way to implement this?

thanks in advance,

Add more info:

They are two different JSON files:

```
Json1:
[
  {
    "id": "device1",
    "name": "dev1",
    "pool": "pool1"
  },
  {
    "id": "device2",
    "name": "dev2",
    "pool": "pool2"
  }
  ...
]
```

And the other Json:

```
[
  {
    "name": "port1",
    "size": 10,
    "pool": "pool1",
    "status": "active"
  },
  {
    "name": "port2",
    "size": 60,
    "pool": "pool1",
    "status": "active"
  },
  {
    "name": "port3",
    "size": 20,
    "pool": "pool2",
    "status": "down"
  },
  {
    "name": "port8",
    "size": 100,
    "pool": "pool2",
    "status": "active"
  },
  {
    "name": "port10",
    "size": 8000,
    "pool": "pool1",
    "status": "active"
  },
  ...
]
```

So I need to create a new JSON file from those two with the following:

```
[
  {
    "id": "device1",
    "name": "dev1",
    "pool": "pool1",
    "ports": [
         {
           "name": "port1",
           "size": 10,
           "pool": "pool1",
           "status": "active"
         },
         {
           "name": "port2",
           "size": 60,
           "pool": "pool1",
           "status": "active"
         },
         {
           "name": "port10",
           "size": 8000,
           "pool": "pool1",
           "status": "active"
         }
     ]
  },
  {
    "id": "device2",
    "name": "dev2",
    "pool": "pool2",
    "ports": [
         {
           "name": "port3",
           "size": 20,
           "pool": "pool2",
           "status": "active"
         },
         {
           "name": "port8",
           "size": 100,
           "pool": "pool2",
           "status": "active"
         }
     ]
  }
]
```

taking into account that Json1 is not more than 10-12 entries and Json2 has more than 800-1000 entries.

So far:

read Json1 (devices), and Json2 (ports) and pass them into two []structs. Then:

```
results := make(map[string]*models.PortDevices}
portDevs := []models.PortDevices{}

for i := range devices {
   results[devices[i].Pool] = &models.PortDevices{}
   m := results[devices[i].Pool]
   m.Id = devices[i].Id
   m.Name = devices[i].Name
   m.Pool = devices[i].Pool
   m.Status = devices[i].Status
   for p := range ports {
      if val, ok := results[ports[p].Pool]; ok {
         m := val
         m.Ports = ports
      }
   }

   portDevs = append(portDevs, *m)
}

devports := []models.PortDevices{}

for _, value := range results {
   devports = append(devports, *value)
}
```

Comment: Does C1 have an array of B1, or do you want to have one C1 for each unique pair of A1-B1?

Comment: Show the code that you tried so far. It's unclear from the written description what the problem is. For example, it says that B1 is huge with more than 2k entries, but B1 is a type with a handful of fields.

Comment: @CeriseLimón it works..but..it took a lot to process

Comment: @happygopher you're looping over `ports` as many times as there are `devices`, why? why not loop just once?

Comment: @happygopher it seems to me that all you need is two loops, one over devices and one over ports. You could even avoid the having to loop over the ports yourself by implementing the Unmarshaler interface on the port type however that's hacky and unneeded in my opinion.

Comment: @mkopriva could you show me how would you do it in this case?

Comment: @happygopher something like this https://play.golang.com/p/y_gqdhrvDqp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are looking to do?  https://play.golang.org/p/AZNzQAwRhN0

What this does is build a map grouping all of the ports by pool.  Then it loops through what I labeled `clusters` and assigns the slice of `Port` to the matching `Cluster` by grabbing the matching slice by `Pool` value.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Cluster struct {
    ID    string `json:"id"`
    Name  string `json:"name"`
    Pool  string `json:"pool"`
    Ports []Port `json:"ports"`
}

type Port struct {
    Name   string `json:"name"`
    Size   int    `json:"size"`
    Pool   string `json:"pool"`
    Status string `json:"status"`
}

func main() {
    var resources []Port
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(resourceJSON), &resources)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    resourcesByPool := make(map[string][]Port)
    for _, resource := range resources {
        if _, ok := resourcesByPool[resource.Pool]; !ok {
            resourcesByPool[resource.Pool] = []Port{}
        }
        resourcesByPool[resource.Pool] = append(resourcesByPool[resource.Pool], resource)
    }

    var clusters []Cluster
    err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(clusterJSON), &clusters)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    for i := 0; i < len(clusters); i++ {
        clusters[i].Ports = resourcesByPool[clusters[i].Pool]
    }

    out, err := json.MarshalIndent(clusters, "", "    ")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(string(out))

}

var (
    clusterJSON = `[
  {
    "id": "device1",
    "name": "dev1",
    "pool": "pool1"
  },
  {
    "id": "device2",
    "name": "dev2",
    "pool": "pool2"
  }
]`

    resourceJSON = `[
  {
    "name": "port1",
    "size": 10,
    "pool": "pool1",
    "status": "active"
  },
  {
    "name": "port2",
    "size": 60,
    "pool": "pool1",
    "status": "active"
  },
  {
    "name": "port3",
    "size": 20,
    "pool": "pool2",
    "status": "down"
  },
  {
    "name": "port8",
    "size": 100,
    "pool": "pool2",
    "status": "active"
  },
  {
    "name": "port10",
    "size": 8000,
    "pool": "pool1",
    "status": "active"
  }]`
)
```

Comment: that's it, thanks a lot @sberry, I really appreciate it